# Display loading screen using AsyncTask with ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, listactivity

I've got an app that uses `ListActivity` to give users a list of actions. When they click one I use an `Intent` to launch a separate activity.

My problem is that the actions that the app performs take about 20 seconds to finish, and since I don't want the user to receive that nasty ANR dialog, I tried to use `AsyncTask` to present them with a loading screen in the mean time. I tried using `setContentView(R.layout.loading);` on `onPreExecute()`, but it throws a NullPointerException which as far as I have figured out is due to the fact that `loading.xml` is not "a ListView whose ID is `android.R.id.list`".

So what can I do now? How can I show that loading screen? Is there a way around this pretty annoying situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what your use case is;  you have a list of items that are populated immediately, and upon selecting one an action is taken?  The action that is taken is to launch another Activity which performs background processing?

Or does it take that long to populate the list of actions?

If the former, you can use an AsyncTask for the long-running activity instead of an Intent to launch another Activity:  in the callback you get for the click on the item in question, you would create the AsyncTask, and in doInBackground you would perform the long-running activity, with onPostExecute refreshing or manipulating your list as necessary.

Another thing to consider is using a dialog box to show a loading screen, if the loading is required to happen before you launch a new Activity.

If you can further describe your use case, I can help you more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. The list loads immediately after I launch the app. The long process takes place once the user selects an option from the list. I will look into the dialog box approach shortly. I would like to know one thing before I try this out... doesn't onPostExecute run after the long background processing finish?

Comment: Does the long process require you to display anything to the user?  When complete, do they return to the list, or go somewhere else?

Comment: My situation has changed slightly... I can now display a loading screen easily, but I have been a bit blind and now realised that most of the crunching is done in my new Activity. So I implemented AsyncTask for the long operation, but my activity still refuses to show ANY kind of interface until the crunching is completely finished, even though `setContentView` is the first line used with `super.onCreate()`. I have also tried using setContentView on the onPreExecute(), but it makes no difference and I cannot understand why.

Comment: What kind of crunching does your new Activity do?  Is it something in the background, which might be better suited to a service?  Does it ultimately impact the rendering of the new Activity's UI?  Ultimately, setContentView will be called on the UI thread no matter whether you do it from onCreate or onPreExecute, so that part should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the loading screen you need to have on the AsyncTask, it's that 20-second Activity initialization.  I would look for a way to do all the setup in a background thread in a Service while the user is free to merrily bop around in other Activities.  I'd try hard to find a way not to just stall the user for 20 seconds.  Maybe take them to the target Activity and show them data cached from their last visit until the new set is ready.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That does make sense. Would that involve using the Intent on both `doInBackground()` and `onPreExecute()`?

Answer (score 0):

Fire up and display your loading dialogs in your onCreate() of the Activity being called, then call Dialog.dismiss() in your AsyncTask's onPostExecute().